# Calculate total once all http calls finish in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

We have a "dashboard" where we make multiple http requests, and each request returns the data for a portion of the dashboard.  What I now need, is to calculate the totals of each portion call.

Each of these calls are assigned to a variable and accessed from the UI using the `async pipe`.

I was thinking of using a [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to merge all calls and then call a method on the `complete` function to calculate the totals.

**For example:**

```
amountOne$: Observable<IAmounts>; 
amountTwo$: Observable<IAmounts>; 


this.amountOne$ = httpCall();
this.amountTwo$ = httpCall();

<ng-container *ngIf='amountOne$ | async as amountOne;'>...</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf='amountTwo$ | async as amountTwo;'>...</ng-container>
```

What I currently have is this...

```
 totalEmitter$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

and then each call makes a call to this function:

```
  private calcTotal() {

     let calc = 0;
     if (this.amountOne$) {
       calc += this.amountOne$.total;
     }

     if (this.amountTwo$) {
       calc += this.amountTwo$.total;
     }

     this.totalEmitter$.next(calc);
  }

<h2>Total: {{totalEmitter$| async | number : '1.2-2'}}</h2>
```

This was working before I started using observables, but I was calling this function after each call, I'd prefer to call it once I know all are complete.  I'm just trying to work out what the best approach is for this type of scenario.

**Edit**: After using forkJoin with the suggestion by @martin

```
totalEmitter$: Observable<number>;

totalEmitter$ = forkJoin([
  amountOne$,
  amountTwo$,
]).pipe(
  map(([result1, result2]) => /* do calcualtions */)
);
```

The `totalEmitter$` now has the correct value, but it's now making additional http calls for `amountOne$` and `amountTwo$`.

Comment: `forkJoin`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`forkJoin` is really the best choice here. You'll just chain it with `map` to calculate whatever you need.

```
$totalEmitter$ = forkJoin([
  amountOne$,
  amountTwo$,
]).pipe(
  map(([result1, result2]) => /* do calcualtions */)
);
```

Comment: Will this make additional calls to the http service though?

Comment: It will make one call for each Observable in the forkJoin array. With order (by the array index) No more or less

Comment: @christiandev What do you mean by additional calls?

Comment: @martin, I still _subscribe_ to the two observables via the async pipe, so when I now subscribe to the totalEmitter$ too, it will re-call the http call for amountOne$ & amountTwo$

Comment: This happens only if the `async` pipe thinks you've changed the underlying `$totalEmitter$` or if you for example hide/show its parent elements with `*ngIf`.

Comment: If you want to be sure it makes always just one subscription you can append after `map()` also `shareReplay(1), take(1)`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your observables emit one singal value each, you can use `zip` operator to wait for all observables to emit there respective value :

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs';

totalCount = 0;

zip(this.amountOne$, this.amountTwo$)
.subscribe((a1, a2) => this.totalCount = a1.total + a2.total)
```

or if you want to keep the observale variable :

```js
total$ = zip(this.amountOne$, this.amountTwo$).pipe(map((a1, a2) => a1.total + a2.total))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a promise:

```
return Promise.all(
  this.amountOne$ = httpCall();
  this.amountTwo$ = httpCall();

)
.then(() => this.calcTotal()) //amount1 and amount2 are resolved at this point so no need for the if checks in calcTotal()
.catch(e => console.log(e))


<ng-container *ngIf='amountOne$ | async as amountOne;'>...</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf='amountTwo$ | async as amountTwo;'>...</ng-container>



private calcTotal() {
   let calc = 0;
   calc += this.amountOne$.total;
   calc += this.amountTwo$.total;

   this.totalEmitter$.next(calc);
}


<h2>Total: {{totalEmitter$| async | number : '1.2-2'}}</h2>
```